# Changing contents of a odbcinstini file in linux environment using shell script

Tags: sed, unixodbc

The content of the odbcinst.ini file is :

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

Here I want to modify only Driver64 line under [Postgresql].

I tried to do it using sed command

```
sed -i 's/Driver64.*/Driver64=/usr/some/path/'
```

But this will change every instance of Driver64. And it might not help if [postgresql] block is placed somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, this will substitute text only after PostgreSQL and will maintain same spaces which line was having before substitution also.

```
awk -v newPath="your_new_path" '
/\[PostgreSQL\]/{ found=1 }
found && /Driver64/{
  match($0,/^.*=[[:space:]]+/)
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) newPath
}
1
' Input_file
```

Above will print output on terminal only, once you are Happy with results then you can use following code to save output into Input_file itself.

```
awk -v newPath="your_new_path" '
/\[PostgreSQL\]/{ found=1 }
found && /Driver64/{
  match($0,/^.*=[[:space:]]+/)
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) newPath
}
1
' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```